# New Ender 3 V2 Neo keeps losing nozzle and plate temperature in the middle of the print and must be turned off to stop the print

Tags: creality-ender-3, hotend, nozzle, heat-management, build-plate

I purchased it new from Amazon in December. It started about one week ago and it just stops with a constant beep and does not allow me to do anything else except turn it off. Doesn't happen on all prints but just loses its brain.

It does save the printing but I must shut it down manually and then it picks off where it left off but still does the same thing. Printing a bonsai bowl and other things and it goes to 0 °C. Is this something I am doing incorrectly or is it a defect in the unit? To me sounds like a defect.

Comment: If you feel that it is a defect, have you contacted the seller on Amazon? Will Amazon accept it back?

Comment: The constant beep is an alarm, which most probably is a warning for ["Thermal runaway"](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/what-is-thermal-runaway-protection), look also [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14449/thermal-runaway) for hints (e.g. cooling fan related?). Another possibility is that the cable to the heated bed or the heater element is almost broken and loses connection after a while, please check the cables. If this helps, we can create an answer for you to accept, else we need to look further.

Answer (score 0):

My printer was doing this.  I looked all over to try and find a solution on my own.  One person said that it was a faulty thermister so having found no other solution I got on the Creality customer support chat and they sent me a file called [`PID.gcode`](https://szscxswkjgfyxgs1.qiyukf.net/a758e1c546fb39cfa1fd61febc8bf86a?download=PID.rar).  I ran the file on the printer and it fixed my issue immediately.

Comment: That link looks very dubious indeed! However, the RAR file contains this G-code: `M301 P19.98 I0.88 D50.29
M500`, so why not just post that instead, in place of a rather worrying looking URL?!

Answer (score -2):

Did you check the voltage setting on the back of the unit?

There is a semi-hidden switch that can be flipped to go from 230 volts to 115 volts. If you are in the US, you want to print on 115 volts.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your answer reads more like a comment, or is it proven that the wrong switch setting leads to this behavior as described by the OP or have you had the same experience in which it was solved with your suggestion? If not we should move the answer to a comment. Please take the [tour] and read our [help]!

Comment: It seems quite unlikely that an incorrect mains voltage selection would cause the OP to stop working mid-print. If the incorrect voltage was selected it would seem more likely that the printer just wouldn't start (or the PSU would fry)...

Comment: 115 on the switch in 230 V blows the fuse, 230 V while plugged into a 115 V socket does not start

Comment: Hey, guys, I am the new owner of two Creality Ender 3 V2s, living in the US. 

On one printer I remembered to flip the switch from 230 volts to 115 volts, and on the second I did not. The second printer would print for about an hour before emitting a high pitched continuous beeping that I could only stop by turning off the printer. 

When I flipped the switch from 230 volts to 115 volts, this problem stopped.

So my original comment was both a comment and potential answer.